# QML AreaSeries with SplineSeries

Tags: qml

I am checking the [docs of AreaSeries, especialy its *upperSeries* property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-areaseries.html#upperSeries-prop) and it is obvious it accepts only [LineSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html) object. However, I want to make [AreaSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-areaseries.html) to be constructed with [SplineSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-splineseries.html) and if I do it:

```
ChartView
{
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    antialiasing: true

    titleColor: "steelblue"

    title: qsTr("Sensor data")

    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark

    animationOptions: ChartView.AllAnimations

    dropShadowEnabled: true

    AreaSeries
    {
        name: qsTr("Air pressure [kPa]")

        color: "green"

        borderColor: "white"
        borderWidth: 4

        brushFilename: "qrc:/icons/UeGradient.svg"

        pointLabelsVisible: true

        axisX: DateTimeAxis
        {
            id: ueDateTimeAxisAirPressure

            format: "dd.MM.yyyy"

            min: ueSensorsData.ueGetMinimalDate()
            max: ueSensorsData.ueGetMaximalDate()
        }   // DateTimeAxis

        axisY: ValueAxis
        {
            id: ueAirpressureAxis

            min: ueSensorsData.ueGetMinimalAirPressure()
            max: ueSensorsData.ueGetMaximalAirPressure()
        }   // axisY

        upperSeries: SplineSeries
        {
            id: ueLineSeriesAirPressure

            Connections
            {
                target: ueSensorsData

                onUeSignalUpdateGraph:
                {
                    var valueX=ueSensorsData.ueGetLastTimeStamp();
                    var valueY=ueSensorsData.ueGetLastAirPressure();

                    ueLineSeriesAirPressure.append(valueX,
                                                   valueY);

                    ueDateTimeAxisAirPressure.min=ueSensorsData.ueGetMinimalDate();
                    ueDateTimeAxisAirPressure.max=ueSensorsData.ueGetMaximalDate();

                    ueAirpressureAxis.min=ueSensorsData.ueGetMinimalAirPressure();
                    ueAirpressureAxis.max=ueSensorsData.ueGetMaximalAirPressure();
                }   // onUeSignalUpdateGraph
            }   // Connections
        }   // upperSeries
    }   // AreaSeries
}   // ChartView
```

I get following error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:304 Cannot assign object to property
```

and the error points to problematic line of code `upperSeries: SplineSeries`.
Is it aught possible to acomplish this task using some other approach, I haven't found it on net.

Comment: As you see this feature not enabled
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68788?attachmentOrder=desc
But you can use some hack. In my case I use SplineSeries and also AreaSeries with  upperSeries: LineSeries with same data as spline, but with of the spline must be enough (7px in my chart) for good look.